# C++ Getting 1.#INF

Tags: c++, linear-interpolation

i'm trying to calculate the FPS of my game, but the value is not stable, so i wanted to implement linear interpolation to make the displayed text smooth.. The problem is that i'm getting 1.#INF values, I tried googling but couldn't really find an explanation.

Here is the interpolation function:

```
float Lerp(float from, float to, float t)
{
    return (from*(1 - t) + to*t);
}
```

How i calculate the FPS:

```
void CalculateTime()
{
    deltaTime = (float)(SDL_GetTicks() - lastFrameTime) / 1000.0f; // this is around 0.02 each frame
    fps = 1.0f / deltaTime; // this is 50-60 every frame
    lastFps = Lerp(fps, lastFps, 0.5f); // lastFps is initialized at 60.0
    printf("%2.4f\n", lastFps);
}
```

Everything seems to be fine.. deltaTime, fps, lastFps are all floats (i tried double too but no difference) but when printf executes i get 1.#INF

Any ideas?

Comment: Your sample is not (quite) a compilable reproduction. If you could fix it up to be an independent example that compiles and runs, that would be nice. And then also use a debugger.

Comment: deltaTime is at least once equal to 0, probably the very first time.  Which produces infinity.  You'll never get rid of it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `deltaTime` was zero at one point (due to a frame taking less than a millisecond to draw). This gave a value of infinity for `fps = 1.0f / deltaTime;`. And due to the way you do your interpolation, once a value of infinity enters the system, `lastFps` will always be infinite.